# "Define what is a" or "define a"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

For example, should I say "We must define a dice game" or "we must define what is a dice game"? I am concerned that the first one might be correct, but has a different meaning: define a dice game in particular, not the general concept of dice game.

Answer (score 2):

- 1. *(We must define) (a dice game)*
- 2. *(We must define) (what is a game of dice)*

"a" dice game, from example 1. could be any dice game.

It implies that it is already understood what dice games are in general, and a specific dice game is to be defined.

The second example **explicitly** states that the **concept** of dice games is to be defined.

However, the inference of the first sentence is only implicit. Therefore it would not be incorrect to have a different interpretation of the sentence. There can be no other interpretation of the second example though.

Answer (score 0):

> We must define what is a dice game.

This would be understood as: *Of all the games that exist, there are some that can be categorized as being a "dice game." We must establish a rule that distinguishes any given game as either belonging to this category or not.*

> We must define a dice game

This would be understood as: *We are going to invent a dice game and describe its rules.*

**OR** it could be the same as the first understanding, depending on context or how it is said.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that "we must define what is ... " doesn't sound right.

If you want to define the general concept of "dice game", I think you could just say: We must define "dice game". [no article, and put the phrase in quotes]

People who know English well would expect you to say "*a* dice game" if you were talking about a set of rules for a specific game.

Answer (score 0):

About your first wording:

> We must define a dice game.

I would reword that as follows:

> We must define "dice game."

You could also use italics:

> We must define *dice game*.

When you use an indefinite article (as you did initially), that makes it sounds like you want to write the rules of a new dice game.

---

About your second wording:

> We must define what is a dice game.

I would reorder that sentence:

> We must define what a dice game is.

I like that wording better than your original, although it seems rather informal (or conversational). I probably wouldn't use that wording in a technical paper.

---

Other ways we could word this might include:

- We must say what constitutes a "dice game".
- We must provide a formal definition for *dice game*.

If the definition is rather short (no more than a single sentence), you could also use a colon, preceded by something like:

- Here is our definition for *dice game*:
- My definition for *dice game* is:
- We define "dice game" as:

Answer (score -1):

Define what is a dice game. - is not a question, therefore that word order is incorrect.

Define what a dice game is.

However, a game of dice doesn't need defining. It's a dice game.

Define what a nice person is.

Define nice.

Comment: philosophical, partially incorrect, does not answer question